# Recommend chess software for windows 8.1

Tags: engines, software

I've been running an old version Chessmaster: Grandmaster edition on my windows 8.1 laptop when I found a bug (Chessmaster recommended an illegal move), and I thought it was time to change my software.

I'm rated around 2000 elo and would like a program that has tutorials (tactics exercises, annotated games, endgame courses etc.)

Any recommendations?

PS. I've checked that my Chessmaster program has all the latest updates from Ubisoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very good piece of software would be ChessBase. Two good engines to run would be Houdini or Fritz (they are essentially indistinguishable to anyone below a super grandmaster standard, although Houdini is reputedly stronger). Besides playing against the engine, you could also store and analyse your games on them.

ChessBase is also the name of the company that produces it, i.e. it's a company that specialises in the development of chess programs, unlike Ubisoft, so you can expect a lot from them.

Answer (score 1):

Lucas is a good software but in my opinion I would say that Chessmaster is better than Lucas. Well you can try Lucas and see...

Answer (score 0):

Join chess.com and play against humans. Training against computer will not help your positional judgement which is what you need to improve to get you from 2000 to 2200.

Comment: Well, here I must ask you, suppose you are playing chess against someone of ELO about 2000-2200, can you tell whether you are playing against a human being or a machine?? Google "The Turk" and you will see that even chess masters could not say whether their opponent was a human or a machine.

Comment: So, if you cannot distinguish between a player and a machine, your answer is not valid and moreover, chess engines can be simulated to required ELO and style(defensive or attacking or sacrificial) while players have a particular style and ELO. To become a true master one must be able to play against all styles of chess, for which a chess engine can train a person better than a human opponent who is  susceptible to blunders.

Comment: I think its a good suggestion in general. Part of the reason why I asked for an engine is because Live Chess on chess.com operates time controls, which doesn't suit me when I want an ad-hoc game against the engine (I have a lot of family distractions. An engine doesn't mind me leaving it for a few minutes, but a real opponent would)